# How to fix Values error in multiple output regression sent in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I am trying to get the summary of the OLS regression of a single input parameter/multiple output parameters from my dataset done but I get a value error

I have a dataset in Excel and I want to check how variations in input, i.e.Temperature (t), can affect the 4 outputs, energy consumed or produced in four different components.
If I run the model for one input and just one output, I was able to see the OLS summary. But I need to see how this variation in temperature affects all 4 outputs at the same time.

The dataset has 1000 observations done from a Monte Carlo simulation and printed in an excel file.

```
X1 = pd.DataFrame({'t': dataset['t']})
Y1 = pd.DataFrame({'E3': dataset['E3'],
                    'E4': dataset['E4'],
                    'E5': dataset['E5'],
                    'E6': dataset['E6']})
model1 = smf.ols('Y1 ~ X1', data=dataset).fit()
model1.summary()
```

I am supposed to see the OLS regression summary but instead I see ValueError: shapes (1000,4) and (1000,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1000 (dim 0)

I am not sure if this is the way to go about it as what I am looking for, is a multi-output regression (single input vs multiple outputs)

Comment: Why not include all components as their own coefficients (no need for *X1* and *Y1*): `model1 = smf.ols('t ~ E3 + E4 + E5 + E6', data=dataset).fit()`?

Comment: @Parfait I tried this but from the model.summary(), it makes 't' the dependent variable and E3 to E6 the independent variables. I read somewhere you have to put 'y' first before the 'x': 'model1 = smf.ols('y ~ x').fit()

Comment: *Y* is just a name for dependent variable to align to the algebraic equation of regression model. It can be anything like *t*. Same for independent variable names.